# Circular buffer writing randomly terminates the program?

Tags: c++, circular-buffer

"The program has unexpectedly finished."

I have a class that is calling `CMem::Write()`.  And it Displays the iteration to the screen.  Sometimes it reaches 140, others... 12, 3, 42, falls out right away... very random.
If I remove the call to  `CMem::Write()`, the program will run forever.

Not sure why it the program termination?  All I can assume is that something is not write in `CMem::Write()` method.

```
CMem::CMem()//sets up the "static" stack memory and the pointers to it; also the "static" positionIndex
{
    m_nBufferLength = sizeof(char); //short int
    static char *cMessageCB = new char[m_nBufferLength];
    static double *dTimeCB = new double[m_nBufferLength];

    m_cMessageCB = cMessageCB;
    m_dTimeCB = dTimeCB;


    ////////////////////////////////////////
    static char *cMessageReadList = new char[m_nBufferLength]; //max size can be the CB
    static double *dTimeReadList = new double[m_nBufferLength]; //max size can be the CB

    m_cMessageReadList = cMessageReadList;
    m_dTimeReadList = dTimeReadList;

    static int firstInstance = 0;

    if(firstInstance == 0){
        m_posRead = 0;//only on first instance
        m_posWrite = 0;//only on first instance

        firstInstance++;//check to see if multiple threads entered at the same time and look at the count
    }
}


void CMem::Write()
{//double dTime, char cMessage
//only one thread can write at a time... so lock... (make other threads with various random delays)

    static bool bUse = false;
    bool bDone = false;


    while(bDone == false){

        if(bUse == false){
            bUse = true;


            m_cMessageCB[m_posWrite] = m_cMessageWrite;
            m_dTimeCB[m_posWrite] = m_dTimeWrite;

            m_posWrite = (unsigned char)(m_posWrite + 1);


            static char cFlag = 0;
            //if writing position == reading position then flag
            if(m_posWrite == m_posRead){
                cFlag = 1;
            }

            bDone = true;
            bUse = false;
        }else if(bUse == true){
            printf("SUSPEND ");
        }
    }
}


void CMem::Read()
{//get the whole block of memory and increment the m_posRead accordingly
    unsigned char j = 0;

    while( (m_posRead + 1) != (m_posWrite + 1) ){
        m_cMessageReadList[j] = m_cMessageCB[m_posRead];//inc m_posRead at the end
        m_dTimeReadList[j] = m_dTimeCB[m_posRead];//inc m_posRead at the end

        m_posRead = (unsigned char)(m_posRead + 1);//circulate around
        j++;// 'j' is not circulating back around
    }

    //write to file
}
```

Comment: Typically, if you run the codee in a debugger, it will stop where the problem occurs when a program "unexpectedly finished".

Comment: Does *nobody* post [minimal complete examples](http://sscce.org)?

Comment: You say this is a circular queue, but when do you wrap around?  I only ever see the write position being increased in the call to CMem::Write().  You should do something like: `if (m_posWrite == m_nBufferLength) m_posWrite = 0;`

Comment: You are using a lot of static variables.  I would suggest making them member variable instead.  In some cases, the static variables will cause problems.  For example, are these values common to all classes? Or just this one instance of the CMem?  If for the instance, then they should not be static.

Comment: @Trenin, when you declar a type a unsigned char and you have that value at 255, what happens when you increment it by 1? It circles back around to -1... then you cast it because the operation was done as an integer, and nowthe -1 becomes 0.

Comment: That is a convenience made possible only when your buffer is exactly the size of a single type.  Also, you are relying on the compiler to cast -1 to 0, which is not a good idea.  What if on another platform, the size of char increases to 2 bytes?  Then your buffer is now taking up 65356 entries instead of 256.

Comment: Actually this is done on purpose... we wanted to avoid the condition statement to speed it up, but what we didn't know initially was that the operation was done as an integer and we had to cast it.

Comment: For the love of everything that is holy, do not use statics in a class that is instantiated from multiple threads unless you know exactly what you are doing.  Immutables/consts, maybe. Buffer pointers, absolutely not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With whatever code you have provided, it seems it is a clear case of memory corruption

First

```
if(firstInstance == 0){
    m_posRead = 0;//only on first instance
    m_posWrite = 0;//only on first instance

    firstInstance++;//check to see if multiple threads entered at the same time and look at the count
}
```

Above code initializes m_posRead and m_posWrite to 0 only for first instance. FOr all other instances, it is undefined.

Secondly, in the constructor you are doing

```
m_nBufferLength = sizeof(char); //short int
static char *cMessageCB = new char[m_nBufferLength];
m_cMessageCB = cMessageCB;
```

Now, this makes m_cMessageCB only 1 byte wide. While, in CMem::Write you are doing

```
m_cMessageCB[m_posWrite] = m_cMessageWrite;
m_dTimeCB[m_posWrite] = m_dTimeWrite;

m_posWrite = (unsigned char)(m_posWrite + 1);
```

Here m_posWrite has been incremented. First time it will write on 0th index. Next time you call CMem:Write and it will try to write on 1st index which is "Array Out Of Bound Write" (because m_cMessageCB is only 1 byte wide)and it's behaviour is undefined. It may terminate on the next write or any other future writes.

Answer (score 0):

These lines seem to one of problems with this code:

```
if(firstInstance == 0){
m_posRead = 0;//only on first instance
m_posWrite = 0;//only on first instance
```

Why do you initialize indices only on first instance? Other instances will have these members uninitialized so obviously they can corrupt the memory.

EDIT (regarding comment):

OK, you can make them static, however this reveals a serious problem with your design. But it's off-topic here. After you make them static another problem remains: the m_posWrite variable is only incremented and never reset/decremented - how do you expect it not to go out of bounds?

Comment: I needed to make them static as well... but problem is still not fixed

Comment: I've edited the answer with reply to your comment. Let me know if it's still crashing.

Comment: the issue is I have multiple threads calling these methods dumping in data to write across a socket.  I am using static so things are kept consistant from thread to thread.  Member variables assigned to a non static address will vary on every instantiation of this class within each thread.

Comment: 'multiple threads', 'static'.  Get rid of the statics, immediate.

Comment: @ Martin James, I need to make a relationship between threads, static is the only way that is working.  If you have an idea let me know.

Comment: You are leaking like a colander every time you instantiate this class.